# 7 Multiple IF formula in excel don't work i saw many false

Tags: excel, excel-formula

this my homework excel about multiple if... please help me
`Result colomn will be ACCEPT IF Age below or equal 32, grade S1, English yes, IPK minimum 4,00 , tes minimum 80, interview good, Other than that Not Accept`
[this link is sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JRvGdX0rjU8-UV2HIMJAeLjskCGZqzXfmNPLrTkf6nU/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` with `and`.
Also if, you want, you can use `if`s.

```
=if(and(b2<=32,c2=51,d2="yes",e2>=4,f2>=80,g2="good"),"other","not accept").
```